# How do method references work with threads? `new Thread(foo::bar)`

Tags: java, java-threads, method-reference

i just try to create thread by using  method reference.

```
new Thread(thisMonitor::method1).start();
```

so how to explain why it works.

does it works just like the lambda ?

Comment: ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-thread-using-method-reference-in-java

Comment: "does it works just like the lambda ?" - basically yes. You have 4 options to create instances of interfaces. 1. Create a class that implements it. 2. Create an anoynmous class of it. And if it is a functional interface you can also 3. create a lambda expression for it. Or 4. use a method reference that has the _same_ signature than the required method.

Answer (score 3):

The `Thread` constructor you are using accepts a `Runnable`:

```
public Thread(Runnable target)
```

`Runnable` is a functional interface with a method that accepts no argument and returns no value:

```
public abstract void run()
```

If `method1` is such a method, the method reference `thisMonitor::method1` can serve as an implementation of `Runnable`.

And you can also use a lambda expression instead of the method reference:

```
new Thread(() -> thisMonitor.method1()).start();
```

Comment: maybe there‘s something that the functional interface cannot explain. just change the void method1 to int method1 , the code also works.

Comment: Is there some language specification reference?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri language specification reference for what?

Comment: I'd like to know whether the concept you stated only applies to Runnable or to other interfaces as well. So why does it work? ---- ok, found it, and at the bottom is the spec reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri it applies to all functional interfaces.

Comment: @newBeeJava you can always invoke a method and ignore its return value. So why should it matter when `method1` returns an `int`?